# In selenium Element not found error

Tags: selenium

using the below code, i am not able to find the element. i am getting error element not found

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class CreateMars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://gimmewings.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement web=driver.findElement(By.id("drop3"));
        driver.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the element you are trying to find is inside of a `<frame>`.  Selenium requires that you use `switchTo().frame()` to access that frame prior to locating elements inside of it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://gimmewings.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.switchTo().frame("TopFrame");
    WebElement web=driver.findElement(By.id("drop3"));
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.close();
}
```

When finished in the frame, you need to switch back to the top, using `switchTo().defaultContent()`.